# NativeScript: Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-10, nativescript

I get this error when i run tns doctor
i googled, stackoverflowed and everything you can imagine, setting environment variables installing SDKs and tools, but still nothing works, so i ended up here, plz help!

> Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to
>   build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later. Run $ android to
>   manage your Android SDK versions.
>
> You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android
>   Support Repository installed on your system. Run $ android  to manage
>   the Android Support Repository.

My config:
Windows 10 64bit
Android studio 2.2.2
i installed SDK 22, 19, 24 and 25
NodeJS v6.9.5
npm: 3.10.10

Please HELP!

Comment: Github discussion https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2583


Install nativescript@next where a fix for the Android updates is already present.

Comment: Check environment variable path and sdk download path may be different.
I have the same issue, because android studio :)

Comment: @Habeeb what do you mean by "sdk download path" ? i added this 'C:\Users\Xsmael\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' in the PATH env variable and i also created ANDROID_HOME variable with same value but still not working....